# how to delete a context

Tags: 7

I have created a sample context just for testing its work, and now it appears on every page because I have used a block in my context. I want to remove the sample context. I have searched in Drupal docs but nothing useful there. Any ideas how to solve it.

Comment: its ok guys. there was a problem with cotext_ui. after i disabled and enabled it, the delete link began to appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do it the same place where you add and edit contexts, the contexts admin page located at `admin/structure/context`. Context defined in code can't be deleted, but can instead be disabled.

Answer (score 0):

1. Download and enable [Devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) module
2. Check your context name under admin/structure/context
3. Go to devel/php and run code:

   ```
   $context = context_load('YOUR_CONTEXT_NAME');
   context_delete($context);
   ```